# Increment and decrement ic c

Tags: c

I'm someone who started learning programming recently I'd like to ask
Why the output isn't
X = 6
X = 10

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
    x = y++ * 5;
    printf("\nthe value of x is %d", x);

    y = 1;
    x = ++y * 5;
    printf("\nthe value of x is %d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried changing values put it didn't help when I use y++ it doesn't increase
And the output is x = 5 when using y++ shouldn't the output be x = 6

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Read your learning materials about pre-increment and post-increment operators. Add lines like `printf("\nthe value of y is %d", y);`. Note that normally you print a newline *after* your output, i.e.  `printf("The value of y is %d\n", y);`.

Comment: *And the output is x = 5 when using y++ shouldn't the output be x = 6*  How can multiplying any integer value by the the `int` value 5 (`... * 5`) ever result in 6??

Comment: Postincrement: `x = y++ * 5;` multiplies 1 × 5 and then increments `y` to `2`. Preincrement: `x = ++y * 5;` first increments `y` to `2` and then 2 × 5 = 10.

Answer (score 3):

When you put the increment operator after the variable, it will add to that value after you use it. Whereas when you put it before, it will increment the value, then use the value of the variable in the line of code.

Refer to the following. Assume x = 1 and y = 1 for each block of code.

For y++:

```
x = y++ * 5;
// Is equivalent to:
x = y * 5; // x = 5
y = y + 1; // y = 2
```

For ++y:

```
x = ++y * 5;
// Is equivalent to:
y = y + 1; // y = 2
x = y * 5; // x = 10
```

Comment: @OmarAlMasry The best way to thank someone who's answered your question is to upvote it (if you've got the rep. for it) and to accept the answer (which you can do no matter what rep. you have).